# Have a Ford Focus 2006 and need to enter code

Tags: ford, audio, focus

The battery had been out as off road. I have the code but what do I press after entering it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If the answers provided solved your issue, please select it as the answer and consider upvoting it!

Answer (score 2):

If this is what your radio looks like:

[image]

- Turn the radio on. At that point, it should say "CODE" in the window.
- Press the "1" button repeatedly until your first number is present (ie: press 1 five times if the first number is "5")
- Press the "2" button repeatedly until your second number is present
- Press the "3" button repeatedly until your third number is present
- Press the "4" button repeatedly until your fourth number is present
- If the code is correct, press and hold the "5" button for about five seconds, at which point the code should be accepted

If you have a "0" (zero) for a number, it will show up after you hit "9" (so on the 10th press of the key). If you go past your number by mistake, you can roll right over to it by continuing to press the button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the radio code.

You enter the code by pressing number one until the correct digit appears, then two, three and four when the correct code is displayed you then press and hold number 5 until you hear a beep. The radio should then work.

Comment: Thanks for your help and radio is working now. Pressing the 5 button worked